# Bro - write two filters for database

Tags: bro

I'm trying to push my bro data to a database. The example with the conn table works. Now I want to add the http log as well. I've created a new filter in the misc folder, added it to my bro-default and restarted my bro but it doesn't add the new table. What is wrong with my filter?

```
event bro_init()
{
    local filter: Log::Filter =
    [
        $name="sqlite",
        $path="/var/db/conn",
        $config=table(["tablename"] = "http"),
        $writer=Log::WRITER_SQLITE
    ];

     Log::add_filter(HTTP::LOG, filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Both of my filters had the same name `filter`. The moment I changed the name it worked fine.